# Deployed Flask App Login Function Not Working

Tags: ubuntu, flask, deployment

I've deployed a Flask app to Linode running Ubuntu along with nginx and gunicorn. When running the app locally, everything works perfectly, but the login and other POST requests don't work once I deployed. I'm looking for tips on how to troubleshoot what is going on.

The error logs for gunicorn refer to signal 15, but as far as I can tell that's a pretty generic error:

```
[2022-07-19 21:50:12 +0000] [734] [WARNING] Worker with pid 735 was terminated due to signal 15
[2022-07-19 21:50:12 +0000] [734] [WARNING] Worker with pid 736 was terminated due to signal 15
[2022-07-19 21:50:12 +0000] [734] [WARNING] Worker with pid 737 was terminated due to signal 15
[2022-07-19 21:50:12 +0000] [734] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2022-07-19 21:51:51 +0000] [833] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
[2022-07-19 21:51:51 +0000] [833] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (833)
[2022-07-19 21:51:51 +0000] [833] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2022-07-19 21:51:51 +0000] [834] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 834
[2022-07-19 21:51:51 +0000] [835] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 835
[2022-07-19 21:51:51 +0000] [836] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 836
[2022-07-20 20:20:43 +0000] [833] [INFO] Handling signal: term
[2022-07-20 20:20:43 +0000] [834] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 834)
[2022-07-20 20:20:43 +0000] [836] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 836)
[2022-07-20 20:20:43 +0000] [835] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 835)
[2022-07-20 20:20:43 +0000] [833] [WARNING] Worker with pid 835 was terminated due to signal 15
[2022-07-20 20:20:45 +0000] [833] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2022-07-20 20:20:47 +0000] [4706] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
[2022-07-20 20:20:47 +0000] [4706] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (4706)
[2022-07-20 20:20:47 +0000] [4706] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2022-07-20 20:20:47 +0000] [4707] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 4707
[2022-07-20 20:20:47 +0000] [4708] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 4708
[2022-07-20 20:20:47 +0000] [4709] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 4709
```

The database is an SQLite file, and read functions work fine (several pages run queries that are returning data as expected). But when I try to use the login or profile edit features, I get alerts saying incorrect password (definitely not incorrect) for the former, and no updates on the latter. I would think it might be a Flask-Login dependency issue, if not for other POST requests not also working.

My Supervisor configuration looks like this:

```
[program:sims-portal]
directory=/home/jonathan/flask_app
command=/home/jonathan/flask_app/venv/bin/gunicorn -w 3 run:app
user=jonathan
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stopasgroup=true
killasgroup=true
stderr_logfile=/var/log/flaskapp/flaskapp.err.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/flaskapp/flaskapp.out.log
```

I'm using the single cpu plan, hence the three gunicorn workers. I also had uncomplicated firewall (ufw) set up, but after disabling it didn't change the situation.

Any thoughts on the best way to troubleshoot this issue? I've tried completely redeploying with no luck. Thanks for any help! If it makes any difference, here is the app in question: https://github.com/JonathanGarro/SIMS-Portal-Neo

Comment: What is the POST request's response status code?

Comment: @RumiraDaksith I get a 200:

```
Request URL: http://69.164.209.59/login
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: 69.164.209.59:80
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```